# Copy blob connector gives 400 error - invalid characters

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App that copies blob between two containers. When I invoke the Logic App it gives the Bad Request error saying `The specified name contains invalid characters.`

I do not understand where the invalid characters are. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with this Logic App/your code, but just throwing it out there... could you quote ("") the URLs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not give the **full URL** for the `Source URL` and `Destination URL`

Actually, the http://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net will be automatically obtained from the connection while you configuring the `Copy Blob task`

So you should only give the path containing from the container

**Source URL:** `importstage/dataentity.zip`

**Destination blob URL:** `importprocessing/abc.zip`

E.g,

Here `testing` is my **container name**

[image]